# Convert the type of value in a dictionary in typescript

Tags: typescript

My title probably does not capture the problem well, but hopefully this code does. I am able to express this transformed type and declare an object. I'm unable to write the function without using `as` cast. Is it possible to implement something like this without using casts or anys?

```
type Tuplet1<T> = [T]
type Tuplet2<T> = [T,T]

type Foo = {
  a: Tuplet1<string>
  b: Tuplet2<string>
}

const foo:Foo = {
  a:['s'],
  b:['s','s'],
}

type Magic<T, N, M> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Tuplet1<N>
    ? Tuplet1<M>[]
    : T[key] extends Tuplet2<N>
    ? Tuplet2<M>[]
    : unknown
}

const magicFoo:Magic<Foo,string,number> = {
  a: [[0],[0]],
  b: [[0,0],[0,0]]
}

function convert<T extends Foo>(input:T):Magic<T,string,number>{
  //????
  return {} as Magic<T,string,number> //can this be done somehow without the cast?
} 

const dynamicMagicFoo = convert(foo)
dynamicMagicFoo.a // Tuplet1<number>[]
dynamicMagicFoo.b // Tuplet2<number>[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overload your function in order to loose the strictness

```js
type Tuplet1<T> = [T]
type Tuplet2<T> = [T, T]

type Foo = {
    a: Tuplet1<string>
    b: Tuplet2<string>
}

const foo: Foo = {
    a: ['s'],
    b: ['s', 's'],
}

type Magic<T, N, M> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Tuplet1<N>
    ? Tuplet1<M>[]
    : T[key] extends Tuplet2<N>
    ? Tuplet2<M>[]
    : unknown
}

const magicFoo: Magic<Foo, string, number> = {
    a: [[0], [0]],
    b: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
}

/**
 * Overloading
 */
function convert<T extends Foo>(input: T): Magic<T, string, number>
function convert<T extends Foo>(input: T) {
    return {}
}

const dynamicMagicFoo = convert(foo)
dynamicMagicFoo.a // Tuplet1<number>[]
dynamicMagicFoo.b // Tuplet2<number>[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhYBGAPDAfFAvFAbRgF0AoUSWBZYAJkx3yIBpYzzxoAxAex7ygBvUlFFQAhgC4qSFBgDOwAE4BLAHYBzLCLEAjafFl10i1Zu0BfUqQDGPNYqgAzPtN798wsROkEA5PJ%20xMw6ovqEAX6skcGkVhyUALLiGio2mKwAcqyJjEKhhADWECBQ6lDFIDxObAYElcRQEAAewBBqACbyMjQYmdreAPw9cui5BGTedQ1Nre1dI8b9BcOGNPTjk2LScGqFajwA7mpx1nYOwFAAtilp7tLJqenurKbqGqxqcFe6EEp5XjEUkIBAADMFCODYt5wgQwaxwax4VAoadSE5djZgCp7FBzgA3P7ATCzNqdbruLAACnUYDgwAMAEoHrd0jBXsp3p9vr9-ujMdjcQSiSSWmSFpSaWo6QzYIz8t4lCg4Eo1EIrPFzo4OiA1OIrmlHnc%20AJhUpgFSXDxGaQdXqDTYjTZ3AA6cRQAD0HsWGC%20Pz%20WAmtt1%20sNrNduk93rWKHoft5geIQA)